# Dagster reload instead of shutdown and restart

Tags: dagster

when developing dagster ops , should I restart the service on each code changes to see the results? Or is it possible to reload it automatically?
I asked chatgpt information regarding Dagster's reloading mechanism.
but the below answer didn't work:
It's great to know that Dagster now supports a feature to help developers iterate more efficiently during pipeline and operation development.
using the reloader="watch" argument with the execute_pipeline function—sounds like a valuable addition to the workflow. This feature can significantly speed up the development process by automatically detecting code changes and updating the pipeline definitions without the need for manual shutdown and restart.